# Changes in System.Net.HttpWebRequest between Powershell versions?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I am having some trouble converting a Powershell script from PS5 to PS7.

My goal is to get information on a remote server cert.

This IP can be anything with a cert:

```
    $url = "https://192.168.1.1"
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true }
    $req = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($url)
    $req.GetResponse() 
    [datetime]$expiration = 
    [System.DateTime]::Parse($req.ServicePoint.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString())
    Write-Output $expiration
```

When run in Powershell 5, this script completes successfully with the output below:

```
IsMutuallyAuthenticated : False
Cookies                 : {}
Headers                 : {Accept-Ranges, Content-Length, Content-Type, Date...}
SupportsHeaders         : True
ContentLength           : 98540
ContentEncoding         : 
ContentType             : text/html
CharacterSet            : ISO-8859-1
Server                  : Microsoft-IIS/10.0

...

Date        : 7/7/2020 12:00:00 AM
...
```

This script errors on `$req.GetResponse` when run in Powershell 7.

```
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. There is no Runspace available to run scripts in this thread. You can provide one in the DefaultRunspace property of the System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace type. The script block you attempted to invoke was:  $true "
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at the InnerException? `$Errors[0].Exception.InnerException|FL * -Force` if that was your last error. Do you know if the system is locked down to TLS1.2? I know I had some issues with web requests to secure endpoints after we locked down our systems and had to add TLS12 to `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol` for some scripts. Something like `If([System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol.ToString() -notmatch 'Tls12'){[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol=[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol.ToString() + ', Tls12'}`

Comment: `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol.ToString()` returns `SystemDefault` which, on the latest version of WIn10, should be sufficient.